# Hotw to load the dynamic data of a fragment to another HTML page in thymeleaf project

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a sidebar navigation with a dynamically loaded versions(dynamic URL's) of the project with toggle and collapse component , when I click on the expand button it will dsiplay the list of URL's. When I click on any URL from side bar, index page will again display the data with dynamic URLs based on version selected from sidebar. When I click on the URL on index page it is redirecting to another page but here there is no data in the sidebar.

```
    I want the dynamic data loaded in fragment to be passed to all the pages using thymeleaf?
    
 Here is an example:
        
 nav.HTML
    
    
    <div th:fragment="sidebar2">
            <div class="container">
                <nav id="sidebarMenu"
                    class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 d-md-block sidebar collapse bg-light">
                    <div class="sidebar-sticky pt-3">
                        <ul class="nav flex-column" id="accordionSidebar">
                            <li class="nav-item"><a type="button" id="collapse"
                                data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample"
                                aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample"> <span
                                    class="menu-title">PI Versions</span> 
                            </a>
    
                                <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
                                    <ul class="nav flex-column sub-menu" id="collapseExample2">
                                         <li th:each="color : ${coloring}"><a
                                            th:href="@{/toList(color=${color})}" th:text="${color}"> ></a></li>  
                                    </ul>
                                </div></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
    </nav>
    </div>
    </div>
    
    
Here is my index.html:

    <div th:replace="fragments/nav :: sidebar2"></div>
<main role="main" class="container">

    <div class="starter-template">
        <h1>Spring Boot Web Thymeleaf Example</h1>
        <h2>
            <span th:text="'Hello, ' + ${message}"></span>
        </h2>
    </div>

    <ol>
        <li th:each="color2 : ${colors}" th:text="${color2}"></li>
    </ol>
    
    <span th:with="convertedList=${#lists.toList(colors)}">
    converted list size: <span th:text="${#lists.size(convertedList)}"/></span>
</span>
```

Here is my java controller code:

@Controller
public class HomeController {

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public ModelAndView usingToList(Model model) {
    List<String> colors = new ArrayList<>();
    colors.add("green");
    colors.add("yellow");
    colors.add("red");
    colors.add("blue");
    model.addAttribute("colors", colors);
    
    List<String> colors2 = new ArrayList<>();
    colors2.add("pinkish");
    colors2.add("green");
    colors2.add("yellow");
    colors2.add("red");
    colors2.add("blue");
    model.addAttribute("coloring", colors2);
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();   
    mv.setViewName("index");
    return mv;
    
}



@GetMapping("/toList")
public String usingToList2(Model model,String color) {
    List<String> colors2 = new ArrayList<>();
    if(color.equals("pinkish"))
    {
        colors2.add("pinkish");
        colors2.add("amity");
        colors2.add("pimity");
    }
    model.addAttribute("colors", colors2);
    
    return "index";
}
```

}

Can anyone please help me in achieving this, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Question has been closed, stil looking for answers.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand quite well the question but when using this link:

```
th:href="@{/toList(color=${color})}"
```

You pass a parameter to your URL that you need to retrieve in your controller with something like:

```
 public String usingToList2(Model model,@RequestParam(name = "color" String color) {...}
```

Maybe it will help.